# What's the first fundamental form of a regular surface in complex coordinates and how to get it?

Tags: differential-geometry, complex-numbers, surfaces

Precisely, the first fundamental form of a regular surface is given by
$$ds^2=Edx^2+2Fdx\ dy+Gdy^2.$$
What's the form of $ds^2$ in complex coordinates $z=x+iy$.

Comment: You can write $dx=(1/2)(dz+d\bar{z})$ and $dy=(1/2)(dz-d\bar{z})$

Comment: Yes, thanks for your hints. Here is my solution. 
$$ds^2=\lambda|dz+\mu d\bar z|^2,$$
where $\lambda=\frac14(E+G+2\sqrt{EG-F^2})$ and $\mu=\frac{E-G+2Fi}{E+G+2\sqrt{EG-F^2}}$.

Answer (score 1):

Summary of comments: after the substitition  $dx=(1/2)(dz+d\bar{z})$ and $dy=(1/2)(dz-d\bar{z})$, followed by a copious amount of complex arithmetics, the first fundamental form takes the form $ds^2=\lambda|dz+\mu d\bar z|^2$ where 
the [Beltrami coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beltrami_equation) is 
$$\mu=\frac{E-G+2Fi}{E+G+2\sqrt{EG-F^2}}$$
and the scaling parameter (I don't think it has a name) is
$$\lambda=\frac14(E+G+2\sqrt{EG-F^2})$$

This computation can be found, for example, in lecture notes [Geometry of surfaces](http://pcmi.ias.edu/files/Riviere%20Lecture1.pdf) by T. Rivière.